# symfony2 doctrine expr subquery: Error: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, subquery

trying to get liked statuses by user.

```
public function getLikedStatuses(User $user)
{
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
                $qb
                ->select('s.id')
                ->from('WallBundle:Likes','l')
                ->innerJoin('l.status', 's')
                ->where('l.user = :user')
                ->setParameter('user', $user)
                ->orderBy('s.id','DESC')
            ;

    $qb2=  $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('st')
        ->from('WallBundle:Status','st');

       $qb2 ->andWhere($qb2->expr()->in('st.id',$qb->getDQL()));


    return $qb2->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

> Error: 
>   Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

BTW: when i dump the $qb->getDQL():

```
string 'SELECT s.id FROM TB\WBundle\Entity\Likes l LEFT JOIN l.status s WHERE l.user = :user' (length=87)
```

BTW2: when i replace the '$qb->getDQL()' for (12073) (id of status) it works...

Comment: how do you retrieve `$qb` in `getLikedStatusesFinal()` ?

Comment: i rebuilded my code, check it now its more obv.

Comment: What's the `var_dump` of `$qb2->getDQL()`?

Comment: Try doing the `setParameter()` on the second query or try doing `getQuery()` on `$qd` before putting it in the second one. Seems like doctrine thinks the parameters should be on the second query.

Comment: @squazic string 'SELECT st FROM WallBundle:Status st' (length=35). Hugo hm... how could i set it to second query? There are statuses and my needs are select first ids based on USER ID in LIKES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As doctrine doesn't support a limit when using subquery ([look at my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622002/symfony2-subquery-within-doctrine-entity-manager?answertab=active#tab-top)) one possible solution is to execute two separate queries which is not ideal but works.

```
/**
 * @param User $user
 * @param int $limit
 * @param int $offset
 * @return User[]
 */
public function getUserFollowers(User $user, $limit = 20, $offset = 0)
{
    $_followersIds = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('IDENTITY(r.followeduser)')
        ->from($this->getEntityName(), 'r')
        ->where('r.followeeuser = :user')
        ->andWhere('r.followeduser !=:user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->orderBy('r.id', 'DESC')
        ->setFirstResult($offset)
        ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    $_usersQb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $_usersQb
        ->select('u')
        ->from('UserBundle:User', 'u')
        ->where('u.id IN (:followersIds)')
        ->setParameter('followersIds', array_values($_followersIds));

    return $_usersQb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can probably do a simpler query, depending on how you did your annotations.

Something like :

```
$qb =  $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('s')
    ->from('WallBundle:Status','st')
    ->innerJoin('st.like','l')
    ->where('l.user = :user')
    ->setParameter('user', $user)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

This should do the same, is shorter and is easier to understand as there is only one query.

---

**Update :** I have had the exact same problem as you did today and resolved it by putting the two `setParameters` in the second query. And therefore I found another way to solve it!

I did something exactly like that :

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('s.id')
    ->from('WallBundle:Likes','l')
    ->innerJoin('l.status', 's')
    ->where('l.user = :user')
    ->orderBy('s.id','DESC')
    ->getDQL()
;

$qb2=  $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('st')
    ->from('WallBundle:Status','st');
    ->where('st.like IN('.$qb.')')
    ->setParameter('user', $user)
    ->getQuery()
;
```

Comment: looks very functional... big hope... but failed, getting still the same error.

Comment: thx! The second query works... why it didn't came to mind me.. oh. Dont know why first but .. Ok that's nice and it will be work for 100% always right? Without bugs, because the inner join come from likes.status_id ... and because of foreign key there to statuses table it has to exists. So no problem right? About performances: It took 7.86ms which is also good right?

Comment: @Trki If it works keep it. I mean 7.86 ms is kind of small compared on the time it takes for printing the view! It's probably not even significative.

Comment: hm.. yea but the view is printed after the queries are loaded or not? BTW: i will keep it, just thinking if there is any way it will broke in future.

Comment: @Trki I don't think it could break in the future! With the situation you have it's better to make a single query with the join explicitly then doing bunch of unclear queries to gain a few ms. Always better to go with what's clear first than going with what's the most optimized.  Because most of the time the bottle neck is not where we think it is!

Comment: ofcourse just was away. And hm... i log outed at web, came back and the query took 20ms ... hm... but it probably can be just because of server on windows right?

Comment: @Trki try running it multiple times, you'll see how much times it takes approx

Comment: ofcourse i did, but now i get it... my mistake was at visited bad "user wall" so it was loading 870objects hh pretty nice 20ms for that number. Thx again, get it like solved and have a nice day.

Comment: @Trki See my updated answer I found another solution today (I know it's late but it might interest you!)

Comment: hm... intresting... no needed now but maybe to future definely. Thx for contact me ;) BTW: i have some question for you but its not apropriate to post it on stack... do you have time for small skype chat?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `->where('l.user = :user')` for this `where('l.user = ?1')`
and add `$qb->setParameter(1, $yourValue);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
$qb2=  $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('st')
        ->from('WallBundle:Status','st');
$qb2 ->andWhere($qb2->expr()->in('st.id',$qb->getDQL()));
```

to

```
 $qb2=  $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('st')
        ->from('WallBundle:Status','st');
        ->where($qb2->expr()->in('st.id',$qb->getDQL()));
```